# определить первые два слова строки js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как определить первые два слова в строке и обернуть их в `<span>`? JS или jQuery — разницы нет.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вот мое решение:

```js
    var firstWords = $('.entry-content.text_cont_inner p').first().addClass('first-letter');

    var a = new String;
    a = firstWords.html();
    var b = a.indexOf(' ',10);
    
    if (b == -1) {
        b = a.length;
    }
    
    firstWords.html('<span class="first-word">'+a.substring(0, b)+'</span>'+a.substring(b, a.length));
```

```css
.entry-content.text_cont_inner p .first-word {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content text_cont_inner">
  <p>Let`s speasdfg sdfgsdfgk about a </p>
</div>
```

Comment: в чем смысл `a = new String;` если сразу же идет `a = firstWords.html();`? Откуда взялась константа `10` вот тут: `a.indexOf(' ',10)`?

Answer (score 5):

```js
a = "Первые два слова в span".split(' ').slice(0, 2);
document.getElementById('some').innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<span id="some">

</span>
```

Comment: Еще б `.join(' ')` в конце было бы неплохо

Comment: Прелестно, однако вдруг разделителем будет не пробел, а, скажем, табуляция или запятая без пробела?

Answer (score 3):

Заменить "от начала строки .. буквы, пробелы, буквы" на "то что нашли ранее":

```
// "foo bar baz"  ->  "<span>foo bar</span> baz"
("foo bar baz").replace(/^(\w+\s+\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

вот такой вариант немного топорно :) и можно сделать аккуратней но суть ясна мне кажется.

```js
function myFn(str, numberOfWords) { // получаем столько слов сколько нужно
  let index;
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
    index = str.indexOf(' ', index + 1);
  }
  return '<span>' + str.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + str.substring(index);
}


a = "Первые два слова в span"
console.log(myFn(a, 2));
```